# calling functionality in ios8 take 9-10 seconds to open dial screen

Tags: objective-c, ios8, phone-call

i have written bellow code for making call, after pressing call button it takes 9-10 second to open dial screen.

```
   NSString *phoneURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:%@", phoneNumber];      
   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",phoneURLString]];
  [[UIApplication  sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

Is there any other way to make call? OR how can i reduce time which it takes to open dial screen?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a threading problem. Is this code invoked from the main thread? If it's not, then this is a problem: UIKit is not thread safe, so you must perform all the actions from the main thread:

```
NSString *phoneURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:%@", phoneNumber];      
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",phoneURLString]];

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [[UIApplication  sharedApplication] openURL:url];
});
```